# Unique KTA Job name

Tags: kofax

In KTA when you create a job it will create unique jobID (GUID). Is it possible to associate my own unique id for each job. Like new field for that job **KTASharp-[dateTimeStamp]**?

FYI: I am using **jobService.CreateJobWithDocuments** method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike batches in Kofax Capture, KTA jobs do not have names.

You can create a custom [Work Type](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.8.0-dpm5ap0jk8/help/TA/All_Shared/SystemData/c_worktype.html) with “Job Name” as one of your fields.  Associating the work type to your process adds process variables for each field, and you can set those however you’d like, including as an initialization variable set by your call to [CreateJobWithDocuments](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.8.0-dpm5ap0jk8/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_job_service.html#afc5a2c3d8eb2b0b9c9d4f5cf30a91e38).  The work type can then be used in a [Work Queue Query](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.8.0-dpm5ap0jk8/help/TA/All_Shared/Queries/t_queryworkqueuenew.html) either to make your “Job Name” field visible as a column in the work queue, or to filter on it.

You can also just use a process variable to hold a name for the job and then use it however you’d like.  But generally when someone wants a “name” it is because they want to see it in the work queue as context for users: work types and work queue queries offer an easier way to do that.

You might also think more deeply about what you intend to use as a "name".  If you are think of creating a name that just concatenates several properties, you might instead just add each of those as separate fields in the work type, then they remain distinct fields that you can use as needed.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Work Type is the one we have to for any customization.